# entity framework and updating contained clasees

Tags: c#, entity-framework

we are trying to write a Generic Update method using Repository and Unit of work (code first approach). the EF version is 6.1.3

the current update method is as follows:

```
 public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
 {
    dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
    context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
```

whats confusing is that if for example a class is passed that also has another class inside it, will it also be automatically updated even of the Entity state is only set for the main class.

apologies if this is a general question but am a novice in EF :)

any help appreciated

Comment: I guess it would not behave like that. Also a class having some inner nested class may not look like a normal entity. Entity should not have nested class, it should have just properties and methods.

Comment: thank you for your response. what if we need to refer another table's data in a class e.g. A `Person` class having a class of `ContactDetails` and `Address`

Comment: See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16419773/5045688).